# Android GridLayout, Checkbox and spinners

Tags: java, android

I am looking for information about GridLayout, I create a Grid layout with Column :

```
layout2 = new GridLayout (this);
layout2.setColumnCount (2);
```

But I wonder how to manage the size of the Column, as premierre is too large compared to the second.

In addition I also asked about the Checkbox and spinners, you can increase their size?

Comment: can share your layout..??

Answer (score 0):

first you must go to google and search about what you want  before you ask

second refer to [Link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Android_GridLayout_in_XML_Layout_Resources) I hope this is help you in gridlayout

and if you want more about android go to [LINK](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/android-tutorial/) OR [LINK](http://www.coreservlets.com/android-tutorial/)